# make complains "No such file or directory" even though the file is present

Tags: go, makefile

I have the below make file

```
PROJECT          := AMS_RESTHandler

### custom variables that could be ommited
GOPRIVATE_PART  :=
#GOPROXY_PART    := GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct

### go env vars
GO_ENV_VARS     := GO111MODULE=on ${GOPRIVATE_PART} ${GOPROXY_PART}

GOROOT := /auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19/
GOPATH := /tmp/gopath_1.19/
ALT_GO := $(GOROOT)/bin/go
GOCMD := $(CGO_LDFLAGS) $(CGO_CXXFLAGS) $(ALT_GO) build -v

cmo_dir: build

build:
        echo $(GOCMD)
        $(GOCMD) -o $(PROJECT)

clean::
        @rm -rf $(PROJECT)

clean-build: clean build
```

The make utility complains as below:

```
/bin/bash: /auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19//bin/go: No such file or directory
ddmake.ddr[1]: *** [build] Error 127
ddmake.ddr[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:163: top_all] Error 2
Build cmo directory error
```

But in fact the `/auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19//bin/go` is present.

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 wur3 wur3 15304666 Oct  5  2022 /auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19//bin/go
```

I'm not sure what is wrong, please help!

Comment: What do you see if you type `file /auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19//bin/go`? And what do you see if you type `uname -a`?

Comment: That output is clearly not from that makefile: for one thing, the error is for line 163 of the file Makefile, and a target `top_all`.  The makefile you've shown us doesn't have 163 lines and there's no target `top_all` in it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet:
```file``` command outputs as 
```/auto/home/lsbuild/desktop-800003/go.1.19/usr/lib64/go/1.19//bin/go: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped``` 
and 
```uname -a``` is ```Linux dur-devvm-0230 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 18:28:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```